# Handling inserts that include a junction table using EF6

Tags: entity-framework

I'm designing a form that allows the user to add a design record based on a structure to a database.  As part of the spec the users want to be able to choose multiple options from a dropdown.  In my database I've created the design table and a lookup table to store the options.  As this is a 1 to many to 1 relationship I've created a junction table.

```
Design table
-------------
designid,
option

Option table
------------
optionid,
optionname

DesignDesignOption table
------------------------
designid,
optionid
```

Using the EF db first option I have 2 models called design and option.  EF has omitted the junction table.

From the dropdown I'm getting a string array of id's back that have been chosen but I'm not sure how to go about adding the entry to the junction table.  Do I have to query the db, select the options chosen from the database based on the id's?  I really have no clue how to do this.

My code so far is below.  As yet I haven't added the code to handle the junction table:

```
public bool InsertDesign(Design design){
            if (!Validate(design)) {
                return false;
            }

            design.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            design.ModifiedByFullName = base.GetUsersFullName();
            design.ModifiedBy = base.GetUserLogin();

            _context.Designs.Add(design);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that, you have list of OptionIds and there should be `Options` navigation property at `Design` model. Then you have two options:

### First option:

As you stated, select options according to list of Ids:

```
var optionIds = ...;
// Get options from database
List<Option> options = _context
    .Options
    .Where(m => optionIds.Contains(m.OptionId))
    .ToList();
design.Options = options;

_context.Designs.Add(design);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

### Second option:

If you do not want to select data from database, then you can set state of added option to Unchanged;

```
using System.Data.Entity;

var optionIds = ...;

// Initialize options according to Ids
List<Option> optionList = new List<Option>();
optionIds.ForEach(m => optionList.Add(new Option { OptionId = m})));

// Set options of desing and add it to context
design.Options = optionList;
_context.Designs.Add(design);

// Set state of options to unchanged to not affect their data and save changes
optionList.ForEach(m => _context.Entry(m).State = EntityState.Unchanged);
_context.SaveChanges();
```