# Adding a record to a junction table when updating a record

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Designs table that links to a junction table which links to a DesignAnalysisSoftware lookup table. It's a 1 to many to 1 relationship. I'm trying to find a way of updating the record and adding / deleting any records from the junction table without touching the lookup table.  I've found a way that removes the records from the junction table but cant find a way when updating the parent record that just inserts to the junction table.

The code I'm using is below.

```
public bool UpdateDesign(Design design){
            if (!Validate(design)){
                return false;
            }

            var DesignFromDb = _context.Designs.Single(d => d.StructureId == design.StructureId);

            if (DesignFromDb != null){
                _context.Entry(DesignFromDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(design);

                DesignFromDb.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                DesignFromDb.ModifiedByFullName = base.GetUsersFullName();
                DesignFromDb.ModifiedBy = base.GetUserLogin();

                DesignFromDb.DesignAnalysisSoftwares.Clear();
                DesignFromDb.DesignAnalysisSoftwares = design.DesignAnalysisSoftwares; <- this adds to the junction table but also adds to the lookup table

                }
            }
```

Comment: how design (input param) created? please add that code

Answer (score 0):

If `design.DesignAnalysisSoftwares;` has PK values set then just need to change state of `design.DesignAnalysisSoftwares;` to `EntityState.Unchanged` as I described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38765748/1380428):

```
if (design.DesignAnalysisSoftwares != null)
{
    foreach (var designSoft in design.DesignAnalysisSoftwares)
        _context.Entry(designSoft).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```